# Where to find InitialAdminPassword file after installing Jenkins in Windows 10?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

After I have installed Jenkins on Windows 10 by following the official Jenkins documentation, I'm not able to find InitialAdminPassword file.

The Jenkins login page is lunched on the browser with port 8080 and it is asking for a password which supposed to be located in: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword`

I'm not able to find this file under that location. help please?

Comment: What options did you choose in "Step 2: Select destination folder" and "Step 3: Service logon credentials"? Did you look in C:\Program Files\Jenkins\secrets? Can you just search your drive using windows search?

Comment: The file is there, you are probably trying to access the full path at once and getting the error due to windows security issues. Because the file is inside the windows folder you will need to manually navigate into each folder along the path and handle the security dialogs that will pop out for the sensitive folder. Eventually you will find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple reboot of windows solves the issue.